# No resource matches com.google.android.gms.version

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have imported an old android application from Eclipse (in my old PC) to Android Studio (in my Windows laptop).

After importing I am facing error in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

The error states:

```
Error:(55, -1) android-apt-compiler: [englishletters] D:\englishletters\AndroidManifest.xml:55: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

I have the latest play-services installed at this path

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services
```

**Note: Currently, this project does not use the Gradle build system.**

I have seem similar posts but it does not solved my issue. Please suggest
Thanks

Comment: where is your build.gradle ?

Comment: I donot have gradle in this project

Comment: why not use Gradle?

Comment: how to add build.grade in existing project, link please

Comment: in your Android Studio, click `File->New->Import Project`. Follow the instructions there. The last option should be to Auto Create its Gradle files. This can import your eclipse file to android studio.

Comment: as described here, you should only use parts that you really need. I had similar problem until I split up the services to my needs. After that, it worked.:  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0):

add `google map support library` with compatible version

Comment: can you please provide some info how to add google map support library with compatible version

Comment: which compileSdkVersion you are using? on gradle.

Comment: like for compileSdkVersion 24 use compileSdkVersion="Google APIs:24"
and support lib 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'